# Let Emacs move the cursor off-screen

Tags: scrolling, cursor

This question was originally asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895313/let-emacs-move-the-cursor-off-screen, but all the answers I got more or less said "it can't be done", which with emacs I just don't accept.

Is it possible to let Emacs have the cursor be moved off-screen, like most GUI text editors work? This is one of the biggest things that bothers me when I use Emacs over any GUI editor. When I scroll down, the cursor is "pushed forward" by the top of the buffer.

I had previously thought that this was completely impossible, because this is hard-wired into the architecture of Emacs, but then I saw multiple-cursors, which does exactly this for the secondary cursors (assuming you prevent the scrolling functions from acting on the secondary cursors). Is it maybe possible to use multiple-cursors to have the main cursor in some hidden buffer, and the effective cursor being what I actually edit with? Or maybe some other clever trick? Or maybe my Googling has failed me and this is really already possible without any magic?

I use the terminal emacs, so it should work there.

Comment: Keep in mind all the multiple-cursors package does is adding fake cursors which aren't subject to the restrictions of the real one. I hope there will be an answer based on the suggestions of your previous question.

Comment: I assume that this problem is specific to using scroll bars, is that right?

Comment: @nispio I use emacs in the terminal. There are no scroll bars.

Comment: So what scroll commands are you using that you would expect not to bring the cursor with you?  In my experience the cursor follows you in *all* editors when using PgUp/PgDn or the arrow keys.

Comment: @nispio maybe scrolling with the mouse wheel?

Comment: Page up and Page down (C-v and M-v) do not move the cursor in emacs unless the cursor moves off the screen. Scrolling is different from moving (the cursor).

Answer (score 11):

There is a new package available on [GNU ELPA](http://elpa.gnu.org/) called [`scroll-restore`](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/scroll-restore.html) that attempts to remedy this problem. There are a handful of different behaviors to choose from, but the way I have configured it for myself (see below) causes the cursor to turn invisible during scrolling commands, and then jump back to its original location when I start typing again.

So far, I have encountered a few bugs, but the package seems to work as-advertised for the most part. You can test it out by installing it with

```
M-x package-install RET scroll-restore RET
```

After the package is installed, you can enable the minor mode with

```
M-x scroll-restore-mode
```

Personally, I am binding it to the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key because it seems so incredibly apropos! This is what I am adding to my init file:

```
(require 'scroll-restore)
(scroll-restore-mode 1)
;; Allow scroll-restore to modify the cursor face
(setq scroll-restore-handle-cursor t)
;; Make the cursor invisible while POINT is off-screen
(setq scroll-restore-cursor-type nil)
;; Jump back to the original cursor position after scrolling
(setq scroll-restore-jump-back t)
;; Toggle scroll-restore-mode with the Scroll Lock key
(global-set-key (kbd "<Scroll_Lock>") 'scroll-restore-mode)
```

Comment: If you have bound a key to it, I suppose that you want to disable it sometimes. Is this mode annoying for normal editting?

Comment: @T.Verron It seems pretty buggy right now, and one of its failure modes is to "trap" your cursor in an area and not let it leave.  The only way I have found to free my cursor again is to disable the mode.  Once all of the bugs are worked out, I wouldn't mind using it all the time.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? I can't seem to get it to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

The method that I always use is to set the mark where I want to jump back to, and then when I am done perusing the buffer, I pop the mark using `C-u C-SPC`.  Even when I forget to set the mark before wandering off, I find that popping the mark usually lands me pretty close to where I came from. This is due partly to the fact that some commands (like `isearch` for example) set the mark without you even realizing.  So through the course of your editing, you have been inadvertently leaving a little trail of breadcrumbs.

From the documentation:

```
set-mark-command is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

It is bound to C-@, C-SPC.

(set-mark-command ARG)

....

With prefix argument (e.g., C-u C-SPC), jump to the mark, and set the mark
from position popped off the local mark ring (this does not affect the global
mark ring).  Use C-x C-@ to jump to a mark popped off the global mark ring
(see `pop-global-mark').
```

I almost never bother with setting bookmarks or registers, but I can almost always find my way back where I came from quickly using either `C-u C-SPC` or `pop-global-mark`.

Comment: Frankly, I think the main reason people want the cursor to be able to move off-screen is because they're used to editors that don't have a proper history of cursor positions. You could also make it so that `scroll-up` and `scroll-down` automatically set the mark, so that `C-u C-SPC` would be sure to get you back where you came from.

Comment: How do you set the `scroll-up` and `scroll-down` to automatically set the mark?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is good enough for me to jump back after mouse wheel scroll:

```
(advice-add 'mwheel-scroll :before (lambda (_event _arg) (if (not (eq last-command 'mwheel-scroll)) (setq point-before-mwheel-scroll (window-point)))))
(defun jump-back () (interactive) (goto-char point-before-mwheel-scroll))
```

Comment: the lambda may need two arguments `(event arg)`