# Wrong number of arguments on lambda key binding

Tags: key-bindings, debugging

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in this elisp form:

```el
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-.")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (ggtags-find-tag-dwim)
    (recenter)))
```

I keep getting this message:

```
Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 2), 0
```

The debugger message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 2) 0)
  ggtags-find-tag-dwim()
  (lambda nil (interactive) (ggtags-find-tag-dwim) (recenter))()
  funcall-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (ggtags-find-tag-dwim) (recenter)))
  call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (ggtags-find-tag-dwim) (recenter)) nil nil)
  command-execute((lambda nil (interactive) (ggtags-find-tag-dwim) (recenter)))
```

Comment: Doing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` should give you more info when that happens.

Comment: I get this error but I still dont get it. updated in the post.

Comment: The function `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` takes a mandatory argument `NAME` and a second, optional `WHAT`. You are calling it without any arguments. Refer to its documentation with `M-x describe-function RET ggtags-find-tag-dwim RET` or `C-h f ggtags-find-tag-dwim RET`.

Comment: Basil, thanks. Then why this works with no arguments needed? (define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-.")
'ggtags-find-tag-dwim)

Comment: @SFbay007 Because invoking a function from a key binding calls it [interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html), and `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` provides an [`interactive` form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands) for generating its two arguments when called as a command, rather than as a function.

Comment: @SFbay007 If you are interested in precisely how `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` generates its arguments, perhaps so that you can emulate them in your own function, you can inspect the aforementioned `interactive` form yourself with `M-x find-function RET ggtags-find-tag-dwim RET`.

Comment: @SFbay007 For further elaboration on functions vs commands in elisp, see also the discussion in [this Emacs SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3555/15748) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12585670/3084001).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

“Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 2), 0” means that a function expects at least 1 and at most 2 arguments (i.e. 1 mandatory and 1 optional argument), but it was called with 0 arguments.

As [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) explained in a comment, you can run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and repeat the action again to get more information. When the error occurs, you'll see a backtrace, which lists the active function calls, from innermost to outermost. The first line is the function that was just called, that's the one which isn't receiving the correct number of arguments. When you've finished reading the backtrace, press `ESC ESC ESC` or `C-]` to exit the debugging mode.

The help for the function `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` (`C-h f ggtags-find-tag-dwim RET`) tells you that its call syntax is

```
(ggtags-find-tag-dwim NAME &optional WHAT)
```

I.e. it's called with two parameters called `name` and `what` (the names are capitalized in the help), and the second parameter is optional.

When the function is called interactively, i.e. when it's directly bound to a key (or mouse or other event), Emacs passes it parameters based on the function's [interactive specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands). Some common examples of automatic parameter passing include the numerical prefix argument, the point or region (point and mark), something typed by the user (arbitrary string, file name, buffer name, etc.), etc. Parameters can also be generated by Lisp code given in the function definition.

You need to pull up the source code to see the interactive specification. The source code will be linked from the function help if it's available. The interactive specification looks like a call to a function called `interactive` just below the function's documentation string.

```
(defun ggtags-find-tag-dwim (name &optional what)
  "Find NAME by context.
…"
  (interactive
   (let ((include (and (not current-prefix-arg) (ggtags-include-file))))
     (ggtags-ensure-project)
     (if include (list include 'include)
       (list (ggtags-read-tag 'definition current-prefix-arg)
             (and current-prefix-arg 'definition)))))
…
```

You can copy this interactive specification into your own wrapper. But since it's complicated and your wrapper is simple, you should instead tell Emacs to [call the function interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html#index-call_002dinteractively-1485), i.e. to pass parameters automatically as if the function had been directly invoked by pressing a key.

```
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-.")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'ggtags-find-tag-dwim)
    (recenter)))
```

---

For this specific case, since it seems that you always want to run `recenter` after `ggtags-find-tag-dwim`, there's a simpler way: the Ggtags package has a customization for this. In the Customize interface, navigate to the Ggtags group (“GNU Global source code tagging system”), and change “Hook run immediately after finding a tag.” to `recenter`. Alternatively, put the following line in your init file:

```
(setq ggtags-find-tag-hook 'recenter)
```

Comment: Thank you for the write up. That worked. However, the (recenter) function is still not executing or maybe executing too early. Is there a way to make ti recenter correctly after finding the tag?

Comment: @SFbay007 I've tried to reproduce this and I find that the target line is centered unless it was already visible in the buffer in which case the buffer isn't scrolled. I think this has to do with the delicate interactions between window point and buffer point, which I've come across before [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21478) [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/593) [3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2213) but I haven't figured out what's going on here. This would warrant a new question. Please explain precisely what is going wrong for you, because most of the time, it does work.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Gilles. I have posted the full issue here:https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36094/using-ggtags-tag-lookup-along-with-centered-cursor-mode