# Using ggtags tag lookup along with centered-cursor-mode

Tags: scrolling, cursor, gtags

I am using centered-cursor-mode to center the cursor at 10 lines above center at all times. I am trying to have ggtags respects this setup after each tag lookup.

When I have the cursor at any point on screen doing M-x recenter takes it to 10 lines above center. However, executing recenter inside a lambda doesn't have the same effect instead takes the cursor to the center.

This is my setup:

```
  (use-package centered-cursor-mode
    :ensure t
    :diminish 'centered-cursor-mode
    :init
    (defcustom ccm-vpos-init '(round (window-text-height) 2)
      "This is the screen line position where the cursor initially stays."
      :group 'centered-cursor
      :tag "Vertical cursor position"
      :type '(choice (const :tag "Center" (round (window-text-height) 2))
                     (const :tag "Golden ratio" (round (* 21 (window-text-height)) 34))
                     (integer :tag "Lines from top" :value 10)
                     (const :tag "10 Lines above center" (- (round (window-text-height) 2) 10))))
    ;; where the center line starts (change with C-M-0/-/+)
    (setq ccm-vpos-init (quote (- (round (window-text-height) 2) 10)))
    :config
    (global-centered-cursor-mode)
    (setq ccm-recenter-at-end-of-file  t    ;; recenter at end of file
          ccm-ignored-commands         '()  ;; Fixed hangs on big org files
          )
    (define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-.")
    (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'ggtags-find-tag-dwim)
    (recenter)))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked.

```
(add-hook 'ggtags-find-tag-hook #'ccm-position-cursor)
```

Comment: Gold to always try to show the whole function at lookup: `(add-hook 'ggtags-find-tag-hook #'reposition-window)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a vanilla way to achieve what centered cursor mode does, somewhat:

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position t
      scroll-conservatively 0
      maximum-scroll-margin 0.5
      scroll-margin 99999)
```

Found [here](https://two-wrongs.com/centered-cursor-mode-in-vanilla-emacs).

As far as I can see, the window is centered after ggtags look-up. I'm not sure how to modify it to get your offset of 10 rows, but it's a start.

The person who wrote the post above seems to be unhappy with the performance of centered cursor mode anyway. For my part, I couldn't make it work on my version of emacs, which is why I found this.